# How can I copy a contact from one list to another in Active Campaign

Tags: activecampaign

I need to copy an existing contact from master list to another list. I tried using ***copy & paste your contacts*** option but it failed to copy. Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the master list and select the contact(s) you want to copy. Click on 'Edit' option and then select the option 'Add to List' and then choose the list you want to copy the contact to.